# Python load, create and save changes in one object

Tags: python

I have an object that is responsible for the project files. That is, it binds everything together (backups, project files, etc.).
It basically has three tasks that are interesting to us at the moment (the others have no impact on the issue):

- Create a project and save its files to the given location
- Load a project from a specific location
- Save changes to the project (I separated because such a method does not require
  with so many arguments, it performs far fewer operations, except
  it does not change the values ​​that are required to be given as arguments
  first method)

In theory, everything is fine, except that:

1. The specified argument list and cannot be accepted in the constructor
   perform creating or loading a project because it is not known
   what the programmer is going to do - create a new one or load it
   existing project (and therefore many values ​​that are created when creating
   required as arguments taken from project files).
2. If the constructor takes no arguments (it seemed
   to get the best solution) it could be done afterwards
   object.load or object.create, but if someone would use
   object.save_changes before loading or creating project files
   project, you could get an error because many needed variables
   would not be created. An exception could then be made, but no
   I am sure if it would not be in conflict with the standards we apply
   in Python. There should probably be the case that one method throws you
   exception and refuses to cooperate if we do not call another one first.
3. I was thinking about reloading in the constructor so that I created an instance
   object could (depending on the given arguments) be at the same time
   creating a project or loading it. However, I have the impression -
   perhaps not true - that Python avoids use
   reloads, especially in the constructor. I also don't know if
   such a thing would be suitably intuitive to a programmer. I have a
   impression that it would be better to do instance = object () and then
   object.load (method arguments) or object.create (method arguments).
   However, I do not know how to make it all agree
   with art.

Comment: I would make the constructor to create objects and make a staticmethod or classmethod to load an object from file (factory method). The method may then create a new object with dummy values or other trickery which stays encapsulated to the object's class. When object is finally prepared with the loaded data it is returned.

Comment: @Michael Butscher
Is this not the second method I am considering, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: As you wrote, a constructor with no arguments could produce an object in an invalid state before it is really created or loaded. My approach would use the constructor for creation (with necessary arguments and exception if arguments are invalid) and a factory method for loading. In both cases an object in valid state is returned (or an exception thrown).